# Apache Camel: How to look inside body to determine file format

Tags: java, csv, apache-camel

We receive .csv files (both via ftp and email) each of which can be one of a few different formats (that can be determined by looking at the top line of the file).  I am fairly new to Apache Camel but want to implement a content based router and unmarshal each to the relevant class.

My current solution is to break down the files to a lists of strings, manually use the first line to determine the type of file, and then use the rest of the strings to create relevant entity instances.

Are there a cleaner and better way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a [POJO to implement the type check](https://camel.apache.org/components/latest/bean-language.html) in whatever way works best for your files.

```
public String checkFileType(@Body File file) {
    return determineFileType(file);
}

private String determineFileType(File file) {...}
```

Like this you can keep your route clean by separating the filetype check and any other part of processing. Because the filetype check is just metadata enrichment.

For example you could just [set the return value as a message header](https://camel.apache.org/manual/latest/setHeader-eip.html) by calling the bean)

```
.setHeader("fileType", method(fileTypeChecker))
```

Then you can [route the files according to type](https://camel.apache.org/manual/latest/content-based-router-eip.html) easily by using the message header.

```
.choice()
    .when(header("fileType").isEqualTo("foo"))
    ...
```